# Elixir socket duplicate STX and ETX in response

Tags: sockets, elixir

I have socket server with this method:

```
@impl true
def handle_call({:tcp, socket, packet}, state) do
  Logger.info("Received packet: \x02#{packet}\x03 and send response")
  {:reply, {:ok, packet}, state}
end
```

I wrote script in python that send "\x02Test\x03" to socket:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))
s.send("\x02Test\x03".encode())
print(s.recv(1024))
```

But the response printed by python is b'\x02\x02Test\x03\x03'

Comment: What are you using to setup the socket? `:gen_tcp`? `:ranch`? Something else?

Comment: I'm using :gen_tcp

Comment: Can you show the rest of your Elixir code?

Comment: You *sent* `\x02Test\x03`, and then you printed *whatever* you received *surrounded* by *another* `\x02...\x03`. There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: @user207421, The op claims the *response* has the duplication--not the log output.  The response should be in a different window then the log output, but I too initially thought the op was looking at the wrong window as well.  Here's the real question: Why would anyone surround the log output with the same characters that are in the packet?

Comment: @7stud What part of "the response printed by python is `b'\x02\x02Test\x03\x03'`" didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `handle_call()` have to do with `gen_tcp`?

`gen_tcp` can be configured to read from a socket and `send()` messages to whatever process called `:gen_tcp.accept()`, the so called *controlling process*, which can be a gen_server; but a `gen_server` handles messages sent to its mailbox with `handle_info()`--not `handle_call()`. `handle_call()` handles messages sent by `:gen_server.call()`.

Here's [an example](https://medium.com/blackode/quick-easy-tcp-genserver-with-elixir-and-erlang-10189b25e221):

```
defmodule TcpServer do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link() do
    ip = Application.get_env :gen_tcp, :ip, {127,0,0,1}
    port = Application.get_env :gen_tcp, :port, 6666
    IO.puts "gen_tcp is listening on port: #{port}"
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, {ip, port},[])
  end

  def init({ip, port}) do
    {:ok, listen_socket}= :gen_tcp.listen(
      port,
      [:binary, {:packet,0}, {:active,true}, {:ip,ip}]
    )

    {:ok, socket } = :gen_tcp.accept listen_socket
    {:ok, %{ip: ip, port: port, socket: socket} }
  end

  def handle_call({:tcp, _socket, packet}, state) do
    Logger.info("handle_call(): Received packet: #{inspect packet}")
    {:reply, {:ok, packet}, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:tcp,socket,packet},state) do
      Logger.info "handle_info(:tcp, ...): incoming packet: #{inspect packet}"
      :gen_tcp.send(socket, "****#{packet}*****")
      {:noreply,state}
  end   
  def handle_info({:tcp_closed, _socket}, state) do
    Logger.info("handle_info({:tcp_closed, ...): Client closed socket.")
    {:noreply, state}
  end   
  def handle_info({:tcp_error, socket, reason}, state) do
    Logger.info("Connection closed due to #{reason}: #{socket}")
    {:noreply,state}
  end

end
```

To start the server:

```
~/elixir_programs/tcp_server$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> TcpServer.start_link()
gen_tcp is listening on port: 6666
```

In another terminal window:

```
~/python_programs$ cat 5.py

import socket

port = 6666
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))
s.send("\x02Test\x03".encode())
print(s.recv(1024))

~/python_programs$ p36 5.py 
b'****\x02Test\x03*****'

~/python_programs$
```

As you can see, there was no duplication of the `\x02` and `\x03` characters.

Back in the server window:

```
{:ok, #PID<0.123.0>}
iex(2)> 
21:54:18.363 [info]  handle_info(:tcp, ...): incoming packet: <<2, 84, 101, 115, 116, 3>>

21:54:18.369 [info]  handle_info({:tcp_closed, ...): Client closed socket.
```

Do you have another process that is the *controlling process* and is calling `:gen_server.call({:tcp, socket, packet})`?

By the way, in this code:

```
def handle_info({:tcp,socket,packet},state) do
```

`packet` may be the whole packet, 1/2 the packet or 1/10 of the packet.  That's the way sockets work. The config option `{packet, 0}` tells `gen_tcp` that there is no length header (0 bytes) on the front of the packet, while `{packet, 1|2|4}` tells `gen_tcp` that the length of the packet is contained in the first byte, the first 2 bytes, or the first 4 bytes respectively.  That way `gen_tcp` can read the first `1|2|4` bytes to get the packet length, say L, then keep reading from the socket until it has received L bytes.  Then gen_tcp packages up the pieces into one message, and sends the whole message to the `gen_server`.  On the other hand, when you specify `{packet, 0}`, you are telling `gen_tcp` that the packet has no length header; and because a socket splits up a single packet into an indeterminate number of chunks, `gen_tcp` has no idea where the end of the packet is, so `gen_tcp`'s only option is to read a chunk from the socket and send the chunk to the gen_server; then read another chunk and send the chunk to the gen_server, etc., etc.  That means the gen_server has to figure out where the end of the packet is.

Therefore, your server and your client have to agree on a protocol to signal the end of a packet; and `handle_info(:tcp, ...)` will have to store the pieces of the packet in the `state` (or in a db) until it has read all the chunks that make up a packet.

One protocol that you can use to signal the end of the packet is: the client closes the socket.  In that case,

```
def handle_info({:tcp_closed, _socket}, state)
```

will be called, and inside that function clause you can assemble the chunks stored in `state` (or in a db) into a complete message, then do whatever is necessary, e.g. send the message back to the client.

If you use `STX` and `ETX` as your begin message, end message protocol, then `handle_info(:tcp, ...)` will still have to look for the `STX` character to signal that it should start storing chunks in `state`, and when `handle_info(:tcp, ...)` finds a chunk with an `ETX` character in it, then you have to assemble the entire message.

Comment: 'Therefore, your server and your client have to agree on a protocol to signal the end of a packet': such as STX/ETX for example? that he is already using?